# Why System.Windows.Interactivity doesn't want to work?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I just added this line to my XAML file:

```
xmlns:interactivity="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity"
```

First I get an Undefined CLR namespace error but after a build it was fixed. Now when I try to add an interactivity tag in mt XAML file I get an complete error on this namespace.

Here is a sample of my code

```
<Window x:Class="ColorTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:interactivity="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity"
    xmlns:ignore="http://www.ignore.com"
    mc:Ignorable="d ignore"
    Height="576"
    Width="720"
    Title="MVVM Light Application"
    DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="#FF44494D">
    <Rectangle x:Name="Color01" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="10,29,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100">
        <!--<interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
            <interactivity:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDown">
            <interactivity:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MyCommand}"/>
        </interactivity:EventTrigger>
        </interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>-->
    </Rectangle>
  </Grid>
```

To help here is a part of my project file with my references

```
    <Reference Include="GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.WPF45">
      <HintPath>packages\MvvmLightLibs.4.2.30.0\lib\net45\GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.WPF45.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="GalaSoft.MvvmLight.WPF45">
      <HintPath>packages\MvvmLightLibs.4.2.30.0\lib\net45\GalaSoft.MvvmLight.WPF45.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation">
      <HintPath>packages\CommonServiceLocator.1.0\lib\NET35\Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Windows.Interactivity, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>packages\MvvmLightLibs.4.2.30.0\lib\net45\System.Windows.Interactivity.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xaml">
      <RequiredTargetFramework>4.0</RequiredTargetFramework>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="WindowsBase" />
    <Reference Include="PresentationCore" />
    <Reference Include="PresentationFramework" />
```

To finish I would like to let you know I installed Blend but never opened it or used it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is  the correct namespace for interactivity within XAML:

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
```

Comment: Could you give me more information about why and when this changed. I followed this tutorial http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/125188/Using-EventTrigger-in-XAML-for-MVVM-No-Code-Behind

Comment: You are missing the assembly name in which the namespace exists in. In the tutorial it says
'xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;
   assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"'
I guess you didnt notice the assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity part as @rohit-vats suggested.
But it is still better to use the interactivity I wrote in the answer rather then referencing the assembly directly.

Comment: @mot - `But it is still better to use the interactivity I wrote in the answer rather then referencing the assembly directly`. Any reasons for this assertion? Using actual assembly is rather a perfect way to use it since most of the features won't be there in the namespace you provided above.

Comment: When referencing via xaml I rather use this kind of namespace since it contains multiple namespaces of the same subject, possibly from multiple assemblies. I agree that in this specific case it's no better than a direct reference because this namespace doesn't include a whole load of namespaces in it, but it usually saves a lot of namespace lines that are hard to manage. The references to windows and telerik namespaces could go to tens of namespaces, that could be grouped to just one.
Lastly, correct me if I'm wrong, using the actual assembly doesn't give you access to more features.

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide assembly name for namespaces which resides in different assemblies. Declare namespace like this:

```
xmlns:interactivity="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
```

Answer (score 0):

First, add the [MVVM Light](http://www.mvvmlight.net/) NuGet package, which will add a reference to `System.Windows.Interactivity.dll`

However, sometimes, when you add a new NuGet package, in might introduce a clashing version of `System.Windows.Interactivity.dll`.

This prevents the project from working.

To fix, add an Assembly Binding Redirect by editing your `app.config` to look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="System.Windows.Interactivity"
                        publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"
                        culture="neutral"/>
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="4.0.0.0"
                       newVersion="4.5.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/></startup>
<appSettings>
  <add key="TestKey" value="true"/>
</appSettings>
```

Don't worry about changing the `PublicKeyToken`, that's constant across all versions, as it depends on the name of the .dll, not the version.

Ensure that you match the `newVersion` in your `appConfig` to the actual version that you end up pointing at:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is also an option to use Blend for Visual Studio itself to add all necessary references where needed. You simply open up your solution in Blend, then you navigate to the view file you want Blend behavior to add to. After opening the view, you have to switch from Solution Explorer to Assets tab, select Behaviors and double-click wanted action, e.g. CallMethodAction. 
Blend will automatically add references to `System.Windows.Interactivity` and `Microsoft.Expression.Interactions`, XML namespaces and also generate XAML code. You have to save changed file in Blend, switch to Visual Studio and reload solution to apply changes.