# Binding to the name of a parent element

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

sorry for this probably simple question but I don't understand how binding works. In the following XAML code I would like to pass my rectangle name as command parameter. I would like to pass "Color01".

```
    <Rectangle x:Name="Color01" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="10,29,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDown">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MyCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ???}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </Rectangle>
```

What should I write in my binding ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass Name using **`RelativeSource`** markup extension:

```
CommandParameter="{Binding Name, RelativeSource={RelativeSource
                                 Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Rectangle}}"
```

Comment: Correct. XAML is too complicate for nothing (sic)

Comment: @B413 - You will get use to it with some hands on. Anyways does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24848328/632337) works for you?

Comment: No, I don't think so because I really think XAML is more complex than HTML and I can do more think with HTML. When I see XAML I understand why Microsoft promote HTML and Javascript. Anyway it works fine. Thank you.

Comment: @B413 HTML is too simple to do complicated things. Note that XAML always has a ***corresponding code***, that's why its syntax may be complicated to some newbie. Here `Binding` is in fact a `MarkupExtension` which allows us to create an inline instance of `Binding`. `RelativeSource` is also a Markup extension allowing us to create an inline instance of `RelativeSource` which can be assigned to the `RelativeSource` property of the `Binding`. Also `XAML` is not something you must do, you can totally use code behind but using `XAML` is easier and better.